# What does this query means?

Tags: sql

There is a table named Employee and it's have employee_id, manager_id, salary columns on it. My query is

```
select employee_id,salary,last_name from employees M
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT employee_id FROM employees W
WHERE (W.manager_id = M.employee_id) AND W.SALARY>10000)
order by employee_id asc
```

What does this query means?

a)All managers whom salaries is greater than 10000

b)All managers whom have at least one employee making greater than 10000

Comment: Seems like [Correlated Subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)

Comment: It means that you need to learn some SQL instead of asking do-it-for-me questions!

Comment: the option **B** is correct for this query..

Comment: @skuntsel we were having an argument so i had to ask it. How this question refers a do-it-for-me question?

Comment: @enderunal No offence, but [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) is the first match on [Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=select+where+exists+sql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a subquery returns any rows at all, `EXISTS` subquery is `TRUE`, and `NOT EXISTS` subquery is `FALSE`. For example:

```
SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);
```

Traditionally, an `EXISTS` subquery starts with `SELECT *`, but it could begin with `SELECT 5` or `SELECT column1` or anything at all. MySQL [ignores the `SELECT` list in such a subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), so it makes no difference.

In your case option `B` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that it means all managers with at least one employee earning more than 10000.
Its hard to say without seeing the actual tables etc.

Think about it like this:

The employee W has the manager_id = the employee_id of the employee M, and it is W how earns more than 10000.

So, M is the Manager, W is the employee and W earns more than 10000

Answer (score 0):

b) It says: give me all M(anagers) which have (at least one) W(orker) (under them) with salaries greater than 10k.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder the type of questions being asked in stackoverflow.

So here I break your query

```
SELECT employee_id FROM employees W
WHERE (W.manager_id = M.employee_id) AND W.SALARY>10000
```

The above query is searching for managers in your employees table whose salary is more than 10000

after that you have exists query`select employee_id,salary,last_name from employees M` to get the managers who are your employees and  who staisfy the salary criteria in previous select query.

In short you will get the managers details who are earning more than 10000